# Run Pkg.instantiate() error when importing julia package

Tags: julia

I have added a package Relief.jl to my environment. I have also checked if it's available by typing `st`and it's listed under available packages for the environment. However when I type `using Relief` I get the following error,

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: Package Relief [e59a39ae-ffc4-11ea-35a5-2b2996f35250] is required but does not seem to be installed:

 - Run Pkg.instantiate() to install all recorded dependencies.
```

Any ideas what I should do to resolve this?

Comment: Can you do `rm Relief` and then add it back to see if that resolved the issue?

Comment: Yea tried that. But didn't work

Comment: can you load it in a fresh new environment? `] generate tmp_env`

Comment: You can try removing the registry and adding it back, solved many times many issues.
`]registry rm General` and `]registry add https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General`.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. But unfortunately, none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command: **] build "name of package"** in the terminal. This should fix the problem.

(Without the speech marks. That is just to highlight its a name)